# DB2 Continuing Support?

Tags: database, db2

I am using DB2 v9.5 with Extended Support but it seems to go expired.

From this page of IBM, it seems IBM is still providing "Continuing Support".

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22002945

How can I apply for this "Continuing Support"?
And what is the end date of "Continuing Support"?

Can I apply "Extended Support"?
And what is the end date of "Extended Support"?

Comment: Contact your IBM software sales representative(s). The people who manage procurement for your company will know who to contact. You can also email to the address listed on the technote page you quoted, and that will get routed to your territory and your  company's  sales folks in IBM.  Such deals for extended support are often associated with IBM enterprise agreements.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to the vendor.